# SQL Statement Database

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Table that holds dates that are booked (for certain holiday properties).

Example...

Table "listing_availability"

Rows...

availability_date (this shows the date format 2013-04-20 etc)

availability_bookable (This can be yes/no. "Yes" = the booking changeover day and it is "available". "No" means the property is booked for those dates)

All the other dates in the year (apart from the ones with "No") are available to be booked. These dates are not in the database, only the booked dates.

My question is...
I have to make a SQL Statement that first calls the Get Date Function (not sure if this is correct terminology)

Then removes the dates from "availability_date" WHERE "availability_bookable" = "No"

This will give me the dates that are available for bookings, for the year, for a property.

Can anyone help?

Regards M

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Try editing and maybe I can help!

Comment: I will try... I want a SQL Statement that takes the current date, till the end of the year. Then deducts the dates that are in Table "availability_date" WHERE "availability_bookable" = "No". Thank you for your help. M

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've almost written the query.

```
SELECT availability_date FROM listing_availability
WHERE availability_bookable <> 'NO'
AND availability_date >= CURDATE()
AND YEAR(CURDATE()) = YEAR(availability_date)
```

Comment: Thanks however, I think I am trying to do something that is impossible in just mysql. In the DB, I only have dates that are booked and I trying to get mysql to show all dates from now until the end of the year that are available. As these dates are not on the DB, it cannot show them. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mal oh yeah it can't select something that's not there of course

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, and you'll obviously confirm.  Your "availability_booking" has some records in it, but not every single day of the year, only those that may have had something, and not all are committed, some could have yes, some no.

So, you want to simulate All dates within a given date range... Say April 1 - July 1 as someone is looking to book a party within that time period.  Instead of pre-filling your production table, you can't say that April 27th is open and available... since no such record exists.

To SIMULATE a calendar of days for a date range, you can do it using MySQL variables and join to "any" table in your database provided it has enough records to SIMULATE the date range you want...

```
select
      @myDate := DATE_ADD( @myDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) as DatesForAvailabilityCheck
   from
      ( select @myDate := '2013-03-31' ) as SQLVars,
      AnyTableThatHasEnoughRows
   limit
      120;
```

This will just give you a list of dates starting with April 1, 2013 (the original @myDate is 1 day before the start date since the field selection adds 1 day to it to get to April 1, then continues...  for a limit of 120 days (or whatever you are looking for range based -- 30days, 60, 90, 22, whatever).  The "AnyTableThatHasEnoughRows" could actually be your "availability_booking" table, but we are just using it as a table with rows, no join or where condition, just enough to get ... 120 records.

Now, we can use this to join to whatever table you want and apply your condition.  You just created a full calendar of days to compare against.  Your final query may be different, but this should get it most of the way for you.

```
select 
      JustDates.DatesForAvailabilityCheck,
   from
      ( select
              @myDate := DATE_ADD( @myDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY ) as DatesForAvailabilityCheck
           from
              ( select @myDate := '2013-03-31' ) as SQLVars,
              listing_availability
           limit
              120 ) JustDates
         LEFT JOIN availability_bookable 
            on JustDates.DatesForAvailabilityCheck = availability_bookable.availability_date
   where
         availability_bookable.availability_date IS NULL
      OR availability_bookable.availability_bookable = "Yes"
```

So the above uses the sample calendar and looks to the availability.  If no such matching date exists (via the IS NULL), then you want it meaning there is no conflict.  However, if there IS a record in the table, you only want those where YES, you CAN book it, the entry on file might not be committed and CAN be in your result query of available dates.

Comment: Thanks DRapp. Are you saying I should create a new row called JustDates.DatesForAvailabilityCheck (Or of course something meaningful)that is populated with the dates for this year. And then run you second SQL?

Comment: @Mal, no, the first sample, if you run that query by itself will create a resultset of a bunch of records that have nothing but a date in them...  From that, you can use THAT result to show all possible dates that are available.  Just try the first query and change "AnyTableThatHasEnoughRows" to your "availability_bookable" table name and see what IT creates.  That is the basis for the second query without requiring you to actually create a table with every date populated.

Comment: Hi DRap. I tried your code on a test at SQLFiddle.com and all it returned was 2 rows, 2013-04-01 & 2013-04-02. I changed the "limit" from 120 to 10 but it didn't make a difference. I cant show you the test page as I cant save it. I didnt want to try it on my database as I might screw things up! Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Mal, if you run EITHER of the queries on your database, you won't be doing anything to data as you are only QUERYING.  You probably only have 2 records because the test database table you created in SQLFiddle only had 2 records, hence it should be a table that has at least as many records as you are anticipating (365 for a year).  Just try running the first query on your database, it will return just a bunch of rows with dates... then the next to compare against availability.